# How to create a scrollable table within Vue.JS with hundreds of records

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, vue.js, styles

So I currently have a working with table with buttons. However, I want to contain the records inside a table with a set size with a scrollable function to scroll through the table. this is my current code:

```
<template>
<div class="col">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead class="table-dark">
            <tr>
              <th>Account Number</th>
              <th>Property Address</th>
              <th>Client Name</th>
              <th>Property Type</th>
              <th>County Name</th>
              <th>Purchased Amount</th>
              <th>Purchased Year</th>
              <th>Action(s)</th>
               <th>View(s)</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="propertyForm in propertyForms" :key="propertyForm.PropertyID">
           
              <td>{{ propertyForm.AccountNumber }}</td>
              <td>{{ propertyForm.PropertyAddress }}</td>
              <td>{{ propertyForm.Client_Name }}</td>
              <td>{{ propertyForm.PropertyTypes }}</td>
              <td>{{ propertyForm.CountyName }}</td>
              <td>{{ propertyForm.PurchasedAmount }}</td>
              <td>{{ propertyForm.PurchasedYear }}</td>
              <!-- <td>{{ propertyForm.Notes }}</td> -->
              <td>
                <router-link :to="{name: 'edit-property', params: { id: propertyForm.PropertyID }}" 
                class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right: 4px;">Edit</router-link>
                <button @click.prevent="deleteProperty(propertyForm.PropertyID)" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">Delete</button> <p></p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <router-link :to="{name: 'protestByProperty', params: { id: propertyForm.PropertyID }}" style="height:38px;width:130.44px" class="btn btn-primary ">View Protests</router-link>
                <router-link :to="{name: 'property-value', params: { id: propertyForm.PropertyID}}" class="btn btn-primary ">View Evaluations</router-link>
                <router-link :to="{name: 'property-notes', params: { id: propertyForm.PropertyID}}" style="height:38px;width:136.44px" class="btn btn-primary ">Notes</router-link>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
</template>
```

I have tried table responsive and table overflow but I cannot seem to make it work. Either that or I am coding incorrectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you isolate the problem in a jsfiddle / codepen? since this seems more like a html/css issue, i think the demo wouldn't need to be using vue.

Comment: also you have two </div> endtags too many in you example. maybe that's where your problems start...

Comment: I tried testing it into jsfiddle but I cannot seem to make it work. I have little experience with css and just learned vue.js so I do not know where to start to style it to make scrollable table.

Comment: the general idea is to give the wrapper element a max-height and setting the overflow-y property to 'auto' (could also use 'scroll' but auto is preferred)